# Why do the analog clocks in Stray have 16 hours?

Tags: stray

In the game Stray, the analog clocks on the walls show 16 hours on them. Since the game implies that humanity has been gone for some time, leaving robots behind, what would be the reason for 16 hour clocks?

The only reason I could think of is because the robots deal with hexidecimal, but then you would think the last digits on the clock would be A, B, C, D, E, and F for hex.

Comment: On 10,11,12 vs A,B,C: perhaps think of it as a translation. In-universe of course there are actually 16 different symbols (or 2), but they're shown using our Arabic numerals to avoid taking you out of the action unnecessarily. (This is not based on any official information, just some possible headcanon.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> The clock, which is blue, has sixteen hours instead of twelve. Fans have pointed out that this interesting detail is likely due to the fact that the world of Stray is largely populated by robots. The robots' bit memory can, in theory, house sixteen numbers, which means a sixteen value clock is logical to a cybernetic society.

https://gamerant.com/stray-16-hour-clock/

Computers count using binary bits and exponentiation. Below are various representations:

`1111` = 15
`0001` = 1
`0101` = 5
`1100` = 12
`0000` = 0

"Where is 16?!" you ask? Zero represents 16.

It seems like 4 bits of memory are allocated to storing the hour. If an AM/PM designation is needed then add one bit to the storage mechanism; `0` = AM and `1` = PM or whatever your robotic heart desires.

I don't know the answer to this but if Stray actually has 32 hours in a day then the hour would require 5 bits of storage:

`11111` = 31

[image: Stray video game analog clocks have 16 hours]