# Why are all the calendars set to October 11th?

Tags: stray

I noticed all the calendars are on October 11th. How do even the calendars in Dead City show October 11th when there is nobody living there to change them?

I thought this would perhaps imply that humans set the calendars and robots left them alone as they're not important to them, but clocks are set to 16 hours so it appears that robots *do* use some external "thing" for time as a [16-hour clock is something a robot would use](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/399889/6697).

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be thought that a plague killed everyone very close to that date so no one *can* change the calendars. So the date would remain at October 11th.

Comment: Do the robots in the city not use the calendars?

Comment: The robots gained sentience long after the last human inhabitant died. It's not out of the question that the robots don't have a concept of calendar days, and therefore don't have a reason to use the calendars.